# Amazon Cloud Watch Maintenance Window

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

We are pushing a metric to cloud watch and would like to create an alarm when the value goes below a certain value.

The problem is that we have maintenance which causes the metric to drop so we don't want to get an alarm during the maintenance window.

I can't see any way of doing this besides disabling the alarm during the maintenance window. Is there a better way of doing this? Can a maintenance window be specified?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for your cas. Experiencing the same issue.